# wget for windows with TLS 1.2

Tags: windows, wget, tls

I use wget.exe in Version 1.11.4 ([which seems to be the latest Version for Windows](http://www.heise.de/download/product/wget-3073)). But this doesn't work with TLS 1.2 as wget added the this feature in Version 1.16.

Is there an alternative tool which supports TLS 1.2?

Comment: Try this: https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Comment: Or this: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: Have you tried PowerShell's `wget`, which is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: No, I havent tried PowerShell's `wget`, but I will. Thanks!